# The js2-mode.el compilation error

Tags: javascript, emacs, elisp, emacs23, js2-mode

I am getting an error when I compile `js2-mode.el` using `byte-compile-file` command in emacs.

```
js2-mode.el:6778:21:Error: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Where did you get the file from?

Comment: https://github.com/emacsmirror/js2-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to increase `max-lisp-eval-depth`: it's usually large enough as it is, but byte-compilation can occasionally recurse fairly deep.  So try `M-: (setq max-lisp-eval-depth (* max-lisp-eval-depth 2)) RET`.  If that doesn't solve the problem, there might be some more serious issue, such as an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a common problem with `byte-compile-file` and some older versions of `js2-mode`. As far as I can tell, it's been fixed for a while now, and the repository at emacsmirror includes the fix.

See if you have an older version of `js2-mode` installed somewhere, and if it might be loaded during byte compilation.